# How to expand a div with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Im trying to do a simple layout with css and html, the layout consist of a menu on the left and some boxes on the right side, the idea is that the left side will alway be a menu. How can I fix that the content never get under the menu ? or how can I exapand the menu

FIDDLE Demo  http://jsfiddle.net/56JdE/

CSS

```
#wrapper
{
    margin:0 auto;
    width:960px;
    height:auto;
}
#leftNav
{
    height:500px;
    width:200px;
    background:#F00;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}

#div1
{
    height:200px;
    width:250px;
    float:left;
    background:#000;
    margin-right:10px;
}

#div2
{
    height:300px;
    width:400px;
    background:#00C;
    float:left;
    margin-right:10px;
}

#div3
{
    height:200px;
    width:250px;
    float:left;
    background:#00C;
    margin-right:10px;
}

#div4
{
    height:200px;
    width:400px;
    float:left;
    background:#000;
    margin-right:10px;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">


    <div id="leftNav">
     <h2>Menu</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="div1">

    </div>
    <div id="div2">

    </div>

    <div id="div3">

    </div>

     <div id="div4">

    </div>

   <div id="div4">

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "the content never get under the menu"?

Comment: if you see my demo, the last black box which is part of the "content" is under the "Menu"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just wrap the div's in another div, and make the margin 210px to left so that is never goes underneath the menu.

```
#contentRight{
  margin-left:210px;
```

}

```
<div id="wrapper">


<div id="leftNav">
     <h2>Menu</h2>
</div>
<div id="contentRight">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
    <div class="div4"></div>
    <div class="div4"></div>
</div>
```

See a working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mtruty/HQ6WJ/3/

Also, ID's should correspond to a single element within the DOM. You should change that second div4 to  div5, or make those div's classes. (e.g. class="div4"). I bet you were just adding that extra div4 to show how the box overflowed, but none the less, it is good to always make sure your markup is valid.

Comment: You are welcome. Go ahead and mark this question as answered when you get a chance.

Answer (score 1):

From the look of your FIDDLE, I believe the question is why is my div under the menu?

This is because you have two `div4`'s.

I amended your FIDDLE Demo which fixed the issue.

```
<div id="div4">

</div>

<div id="div4"> -Remove this!

</div> -And this!
```

Having two `div4`'s caused the total width to exceed your wrapper width making the `float:left`property move the `div` to under your menu.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a wrapper around content, and set the apropriate width's so they match the parent wrapper.

```
<div id="leftNav">
 <h2>Menu</h2>
</div>
<div id="content_wrapper">
     ...
</div>
```

See fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/56JdE/2/

Answer (score 0):

There's two simple ways you could do this. Either add some padding to the wrapper, maybe 20% to the left or whatever the width of the menu would be, and then absolutely position that menu to the left.

OR

You could create a parent container for your content, within the wrapper, and float both the menu ( first ) and the new container to fill up the wrapper accordingly. If you go the float method you'd have to add a clear somewhere after the content to keep the wrapper from collapsing, or float it as well.

```
.wrapper {
    margin:0 auto;
}
.menu {
    height:500px;
    width:20%;
    float: left;
    background: red;
}
.content {
    width: 80%;
    float: left;
}
```

Full example @ http://jsfiddle.net/M58C6/2/